# How to pass values from one activity to another using tap on List Item

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, adapter, baseadapter

I am trying to pass ciicked listitem data to another activity, but whenever i do tap on any of the list item neither able to get Toast nor able to pass selected list item value to another activity.

So here i want to know:

> How to pass values from one activity to another using tap on List Item ?

and second

> why not showing tapped list item position into Toast ?

**MainActivity.java:**

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();

            listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SingleItemView.class);
                    // Pass all data rank
                    intent.putExtra("rank", arraylist.get(position).get(MainActivity.RANK));
                    // Start SingleItemView Class
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });         
        }
```

After putting **Log.d** getting error, please check complete log below

```
@Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.d("RANK::", arraylist.get(position).get(MainActivity.RANK));
```

**Log:**

```
06-04 18:21:12.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19957): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-04 18:21:12.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19957): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
06-04 18:21:12.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19957):    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:242)
06-04 18:21:12.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19957):    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:304)
06-04 18:21:12.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19957):    at com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial.MainActivity$DownloadJSON$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:107)
06-04 18:21:12.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19957):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
06-04 18:21:12.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19957):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1280)
06-04 18:21:12.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19957):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3071)
06-04 18:21:12.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19957):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3972)
06-04 18:21:12.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19957):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-04 18:21:12.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19957):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-04 18:21:12.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19957):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-04 18:21:12.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19957):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
06-04 18:21:12.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19957):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 18:21:12.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19957):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-04 18:21:12.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19957):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1036)
06-04 18:21:12.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19957):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:803)
06-04 18:21:12.725: E/AndroidRuntime(19957):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Comment: i don't know but whenever i do tap on any of the list item, not getting what i wanted ... @Raghunandan

Comment: can you log the value of  `arraylist.get(position).get(MainActivity.RANK)`

Comment: @Raghunandan please check my posted code !

Comment: what is line 107 `MainActivity.java`?

Comment: @Raghunandan sorry forgot to tell you, this is the line number: 107  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, position+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

to

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try writing following lines in onCreat instead of onPostExecute

```
listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SingleItemView.class);
                    // Pass all data rank
                    intent.putExtra("rank", arraylist.get(position).get(MainActivity.RANK));
                    // Start SingleItemView Class
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using setTag(Object) and getTag() methods. Apply setTag() on each view representing row in your ListView. Then, in onItemClick() method use "view" variable which is passed as a paremeter to extract passed value using getTag(). Your solution looks fine but using Tags to pass values to onClicks is adviced because of optimisation reasons.